# How to render a building using Three.js extrusion method?

Tags: three.js, procedural

I'm trying to render a 3D building procedurally using Three.js. One of the ways this is done is by extruding a square/rectangle. See Fig. 19 here: http://www.gamesitb.com/SurveyProcedural.pdf

I've looked at the Three.js documentation for the ExtrudeGeometry API, but its usage isn't very clear. Have searched the web and this forum for possible examples/code snippets - in vain! Any pointers on this would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place to look is in this example that is provided in the THREE.js zip.

examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html

The next bits are for example purposes.

The key points are that you create a series of Vector2 (lines 144-165 in the file I've mentioned) that define the corners of the building.

```
var californiaPts = [];
californiaPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( 610, 320 ) );
californiaPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( 450, 300 ) );
californiaPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( 392, 392 ) );
californiaPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( 266, 438 ) );
```

The next step is to convert those lines to a THREE.Shape (line 167)

```
var californiaShape = new THREE.Shape( californiaPts );
```

Then you want to extrude the shape.

```
var extrudeSettings = { amount: 20 }; // bevelSegments: 2, steps: 2 , bevelSegments: 5, bevelSize: 8, bevelThickness:5

var geometry = californiaShape.extrude(extrudeSettings);
```

At this point you'd have an extrusion of the shape that is a geometry object so it can be turned into a mesh and you can apply a material to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and example snippet. This has certainly helped. Let me create a prototype using these and post the results.

Comment: I'm drawing mine as 4 separate shapes, one for each wall, then I extrude them.  I do the 4 shapes so each wall can have its own textures.  Then I merge the geometries into one building.  I assume that based on the PDF you listed you may want to do it that way as well so you have since the buildings would not be fully symmetrical.

Comment: Yes, that's what I plan to do as well. That would give a more realistic rendering of the overall city. Thanks again.